# Use the category name instead of category slug in permalinks

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, categories, slug, permalinks

How to create a permalink structure which finish by:

```
/category-name/post-name/
```

Instead of:

```
/category-slug/post-name/
```

By default, Wordpress is offering `%category%` tag strucure as ["A sanitized version of the category name (category slug field on New/Edit Category panel"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags).

How can I use the category name instead of category slug in permalinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'category_name_rewrite_rule');
function category_name_rewrite_rule($rules) {
    $new_rules = array();
    $categories = get_categories();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $cat_name = preg_replace('#\s+#', '-', $category->name);
        $new_rules['/'.$category->slug}.'/'] = '/'.url_encode($cat_name).'/';
    }
    return $new_rules + $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I've found the solution - Instead of **Categories**, use **Custom_post_types**...
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/how-to-change-permalink-structure-for-custom-post-type-and-its-taxonomies/#167992